# How to show alert when Location is disabled by the user in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, core-location, cllocationmanager

My Swift app asks to allow access to current location via CLLocationManager. How can I display an alert message when the user taps on "Don't Allow"?

Comment: 'authorizationStatus()' was deprecated in iOS 14.0 ... see topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63788488/checking-user-location-permission-status-on-ios-14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to look at

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
```

and

```
CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
```

The first is invoked when the user changes authorization status and the second will allow you to determine current status at any time.

Then, displaying the message, for example:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Your title", message: "GPS access is restricted. In order to use tracking, please enable GPS in the Settigs app under Privacy, Location Services.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings now", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
                print("")
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
            }))
```

the code above shows an alert and allows the user to go directly to settings to enable location.

Comment: Awesome help, @MirekE! Thanks :)