# Checking user location permission status on iOS 14

Tags: swift, location, ios14

So I wanted to check if I have access to the user location on iOS14 or not & I found this code but XCode(12) yells at me with this:

```
'authorizationStatus()' was deprecated in iOS 14.0
```

And here is the code:

```
func hasLocationPermission() -> Bool {
       var hasPermission = false
       if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
           switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() { // <= 'authorizationStatus()' was deprecated in iOS 14.0
           case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
               hasPermission = false
           case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
               hasPermission = true
           @unknown default:
               hasPermission = false
             }
       } else {
            hasPermission = false
       }
        return hasPermission
}
```

So what should I use instead?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/3563952-authorizationstatus

Comment: I can't understand anything from apple documentation :|

Comment: You're supposed to implement the delegate method `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization` and check the value of `authorizationStatus` inside that method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In iOS 14 'authorizationStatus()' is deprecated :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423523-authorizationstatus

You should use locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization instead:

```
func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {

        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
            case .authorizedAlways , .authorizedWhenInUse:
                break
            case .notDetermined , .denied , .restricted:
                break
            default:
                break
        }
        
        switch manager.accuracyAuthorization {
            case .fullAccuracy:
                break
            case .reducedAccuracy:
                break
            default:
                break
        }
}
```

Comment: locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_:)  is only  available for iOS14.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/3563956-locationmanagerdidchangeauthoriz

Answer (score 8):

iOS 14 and earlier version

```
func locationAuthorizationStatus() -> CLAuthorizationStatus {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var locationAuthorizationStatus : CLAuthorizationStatus
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        locationAuthorizationStatus =  locationManager.authorizationStatus
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        locationAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    }
    return locationAuthorizationStatus
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> iOS 14 Check user is allow permission

```
extension CLLocationManager {
    
    func checkLocationPermission() {
        
        if self.authorizationStatus != .authorizedWhenInUse && self.authorizationStatus != .authorizedAlways {
            
            self.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

> Use

```
self.LocationManager.checkLocationPermission()
```